# How to use 'System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged' to encrypt a byte[]?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

Basically i want to use System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged (or a better class, if you think there is one?) to take one byte array and create another encrypted byte array, using a given symmetric key (i assume i'll need one?).

I also will need the way to reverse this procedure.

The point of this is so i can encrypt stored passwords. I assume there's a simple way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

EDIT: You really should generate a random IV each time you encrypt, unlike my ancient code below:

Here's what i did in the end, inspired by (an older version of) michael's answer:

```
private string Encrypt(string input)
{
  return Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input)));
}
private byte[] Encrypt(byte[] input)
{
  PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes("hjiweykaksd", new byte[] { 0x43, 0x87, 0x23, 0x72, 0x45, 0x56, 0x68, 0x14, 0x62, 0x84 });
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  Aes aes = new AesManaged();
  aes.Key = pdb.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
  aes.IV = pdb.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize / 8);
  CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
  cs.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
  cs.Close();
  return ms.ToArray();
}
private string Decrypt(string input)
{
  return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(input)));
}
private byte[] Decrypt(byte[] input)
{
  PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes("hjiweykaksd", new byte[] { 0x43, 0x87, 0x23, 0x72, 0x45, 0x56, 0x68, 0x14, 0x62, 0x84 });
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  Aes aes = new AesManaged();
  aes.Key = pdb.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
  aes.IV = pdb.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize / 8);
  CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
  cs.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
  cs.Close();
  return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Given your code above, you're going to end up with the same key every time, which is good, **but you will also end up with the same IV every time, which is bad**.  I'm pretty sure that the IV should be specific to the data that you're encrypting, while the Key can be "global".

Comment: [This answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3970/8499) provides a great explanation of the initialization vector (IV) and why it should be different for every message you encrypt. It is not secret, and is sent along with the ciphertext.

Comment: @metadaddy updated with comment to reflect that

Comment: @Chris look into the `using` statement with regards to the numerous `IDisposable`-implemented objects you're instantiating directly and indirectly.

Answer (score 12):

EDIT: Noticed eed3si9n's edit...  I agree, symmetric encryption is a bad choice for passwords.  Use hashes (and **not** MD5) instead.  Here's [a very complete example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table).

A simple example:

```
byte[] clear = GetCleartext();
HashAlgorithm sha2 = SHA256CryptoServiceProvider.Create();
byte[] hashed = sha2.ComputeHash(clear);
```

To validate a correct password, you would run the same computation over the provided password, and compare the result to the hash you have in your database.

It's good practice to add salt (random data) to the cleartext to avoid [rainbow table attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table).  Basically, append a known randomly-generated value, unique to that user, to the cleartext before hashing.

Comment: And a clarification: the salt value needs to be kept along with the hash for the later comparisons. And generate a new salt every time the user changes the password.

Comment: I need the passwords to pass them on to another service.

Answer (score 8):

[Simple encrypting and decrypting data in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/DotNetCrypto.aspx).

**Edit**: For passwords, I would recommend using [BCrypt](http://bcrypt.codeplex.com/) instead of doing a two-way encryption, unless you really need to recover the original password. Normally you just need the fact that someone knew the password, not the password itself.

Comment: Looks good, but what's an IV ? I thought i'd just need a 16-byte key?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector. You can increase the strength if you put random stuff in there, but you could use zeros too.

Comment: I need the passwords to pass them on to another service.

Answer (score 2):

There is a pretty nice C# implementation of symmetric key encryption at https://web.archive.org/web/20120326090435/http://www.superstarcoders.com/blogs/posts/symmetric-encryption-in-c-sharp.aspx . It supports AES, Triple DES, and Rijndael. It has easy to follow functions in the form:

```
 string Encrypt(string plaintext, string password, string salt)
```

Comment: This URL is dead and archive.org doesn't have a copy, either.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated answer with a working archive.org backup

Answer (score 0):

The OP states they have to pass the credentials to another service, which is a completely different issue than password storage and verification.

Depending on how much control you have over the partner service, or what they expose, the best solutions involve a vendor provided or industry standard approaches such as Kerberos, SAML or other stable, secure bearer token means to flow trust. This is a deep topic.

But let's assume you need to pass credentials via Basic Auth SSL/TLS. So now you need to store them securely in a reversible manner. To solve this problem, I have had success with the secret key being conveyed using a certificate private key. This affords some protection of your secret by the operating system and allows for OPS folks to manage the keys, which is desirable. The account used to run your process must be granted rights to see the private key, which then terminates the trust chain at the OS.

You still might have to think about key rotation, which will require you to store a version number with the cipher text.

Also, SecureString might be of interest, but until all .NET API's allow SecureString to be passed as part of a credential, often times you end up with a string on the managed heap you cannot destroy.

Anyway, this isn't a spoon fed answer with code, but from experience, I have found that managing the chain of secrets is always a problem, and if you cannot terminate at a hardened infrastructure such as Active Directory, certificates are the next best thing.