# Encrypt File As Posted to FTP Site

Tags: c#, encryption, ftp

I'm using VS 2010 (C#). I'm trying to encrypt (decrypt) a file as it is being uploaded (downloaded) from an FTP site.  I thought this would be quicker than using a local temp file to encrypt before upload and decrypt after download.  I get an error on the code below.  I just can't seem to get the various stream types in alignment (i.e. FileStream, CryptoStream, and Stream).  Any help is much appreciated.

```
public void Upload(byte[] desKey, byte[] desIV)
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Destination);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);

        FileStream fStream = File.Open(SourceFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

        CryptoStream responseStream = new CryptoStream(fStream, new DESCryptoServiceProvider().CreateDecryptor(desKey, desIV), CryptoStreamMode.Read);

        byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseStream.ToString());

        responseStream.Close();  ///ERROR here
        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        response.Close();
    }
```

Unit Test:

```
public void CleanEncryptUploadTest()
    {           
        FT.ftp uploadTest = new FT.ftp();

        uploadTest.UserName = "ausername";
        uploadTest.Password = "apassword";
        uploadTest.SourceFile = "D:\\Temp\\Test\\file.txt";
        uploadTest.Destination = "ftp://ftp.mysite.com/test2.txt";

        byte[] key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("TestZone");
        byte[] initVector = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("TestZone");

        uploadTest.Upload(key, initVector);
    }
```

Comment: What made you thi k this would be quicker?

Comment: thought that encyption in memory of a large file and then writing it directly to the website is quicker than reading source file, creating an encrypted copy on the local machine, and finally uploading the encrypted file. I could be wrong.

Comment: Test method CleanEncryptUploadTest threw exception: 
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Bad Data.

Comment: Could you post the test method?

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967773/how-to-use-system-security-cryptography-aesmanaged-to-encrypt-a-byte

Comment: Shouldn't there be CreateEncryptor() instead of CreateDecryptor() ?The second problem i see is that responseStream.ToString() returns name of class, not content of file.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I used a memory stream and wrote the encrypted bytes to it instead.  Also changed the cryptostream mode to write.

```
    public void Upload(byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        byte[] fileContents;

        using (FileStream inputeFile = new FileStream(this.SourceFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (MemoryStream encryptedStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryptostream = new CryptoStream(encryptedStream, new DESCryptoServiceProvider().CreateEncryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    byte[] bytearrayinput = new byte[inputeFile.Length];
                    inputeFile.Read(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
                    cryptostream.Write(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
                    fileContents = encryptedStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }

        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(this.Destination);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(this.UserName, this.Password);
        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        response.Close();
    }
```