# Setting Key of System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged in C#

Tags: aes

When I instantiate AesManaged in C#, it already has the .Key property set. Is it safe to use it? I.e. is it cryptographically strong and random enough for each new instantiation of AesManaged (and every time I call .GenerateKey() on an existing instance)?

All examples I've seen, first generate a random password and then use a key derivation function like Rfc2898DeriveBytes or PasswordDeriveBytes to generate the Key (e.g. [How to use 'System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged' to encrypt a byte[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967773/how-to-use-system-security-cryptography-aesmanaged-to-encrypt-a-byte)). This requires additional information - like salt value, number of password iterations, what hash algorithm to use.

I understand I need all that if I want my users to come up with passwords. I then need to produce random cryptographically strong Keys from them. But if everything is generated by the computer, do I need to programmatically generate random passwords and then Keys from them, or can I just use whatever AesManaged.Key contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the default Key and IV values if you like. You can also explicitly regenerate a new random one with:

[SymmetricAlgorithm.GenerateKey()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09d0kyb3(v=vs.110).aspx) or [SymmetricAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor(null, null)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.generatekey(v=vs.110).aspx)

It depends on what you are protecting and how many owners of information you need to support. If speed / volume doesn't matter, then you are still better adopting PBKDF2 by using [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=vs.110).aspx) for the iterations.

Regardless, you don't want to share the key across multiple users / tenants / security "realms", however, but sure you can use the default key for a single application. If you do, combine the salt with it.

The reasons we use user defined passwords and salts are to avoid attacks that exploit common/weak passwords or shared passwords between users and to ensure as application owners don't know their keys.

The reasons we use PBKDF2 (derivation with many iterations) is to slow down the attacker. Penalty we pay 1 time per user is paid many times by an attacker.

If your needs are just to have a random key for a single application or system, then the default is usable, assuming, of course, it provides the strength you need.

Comment: `CreateEncryptor()` (no arguments) uses the key from the Key property.  Did you mean `GenerateKey()` to make a new one?

Comment: @bartonjs - Yes thanks for the correction. I updated, and also tried to answer the base question better.