# SHA512 with salt encoding in powershell

Tags: powershell, sha512

I am trying to generate a SHA512 hash password string with salt encoding in powershell..

I found below python one and checked working fine

```
python -c 'import crypt; print crypt.crypt("welcome@123", crypt.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512))'
```

Is there anything similar in powershell...??

Comment: is this what you are after: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967773/how-to-use-system-security-cryptography-aesmanaged-to-encrypt-a-byte

Comment: Is it same as salt encoding ..?? coz when i tested the python script in one of the linux box for a user it worked exactly  fine...so just need to confirm..